# Why does `<Bar>` behave like `|` in the `:command` command in Vim?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, escape, map-operator, command

Here is the list of experiments I performed that shows that `<Bar>` is treated as literal `<Bar>` in some commands but it is treated as `|` in the `:command` command.

I am trying to understand why or what in the documentation dictates that `<Bar>` should be treated as `|` in the `:command` command.

#### Case 1: `:!` and `<Bar>`

Enter this command-line mode command in Vim:

```
:!uname <Bar> grep i
```

We get this error:

```
/bin/bash: Bar: No such file or directory
```

This error occurred because the following shell command was invoked: `uname < Bar > grep i` and there is no file named `Bar` to redirect the standard input of `uname` to.

We see that the string `<Bar>` was literally sent to the shell.

#### Case 2: `:echo` and `<Bar>`

Enter this command-line mode command in Vim:

```
:echo 'hi' <Bar> echo 'bye'
```

We get this error:

```
E121: Undefined variable: Bar
E15: Invalid expression: 'hi' <Bar> echo 'bye'
```

Once again `<Bar>` was literally used as argument in the `:echo` command.

#### Case 3: `:command`, `:!` and `<Bar>`

Enter these command-line mode commands in Vim:

```
:command! A !uname <Bar> grep i
:A
```

I get this output:

```
Darwin
```

You may get `Linux` in your output.

The argument `<Bar>` was interpreted as `|`.

#### Case 4: `:command`, `:echo` and `<Bar>`

Enter these command-line mode commands in Vim:

```
:command! A echo 'hi' <Bar> echo 'bye'
:A
```

We get this output:

```
hi
bye
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Again, the argument `<Bar>` was interpreted as `|`.

#### Question

Why is `<Bar>` treated as 5-character literal argument in case of `:!`, `:echo`, etc. but it is treated as `|` in `:command`? I searched the documentation but I can't seem to find anything.

The documentation does mention that `<Bar>` can be treated as `|` in the `:map` and some other commands, but it never mentions anything about it being treated as `|` in the `:command` command.

Here are some excerpts from the documentation that one can find by entering `:helpgrep <Bar>`:

1. This talks about usage of `<Bar>` in the `:map` command. See `:help :bar`.

   ```
    There is one exception: When the 'b' flag is present in 'cpoptions', with the
    ":map" and ":abbr" commands and friends CTRL-V needs to be used instead of
    '\'.  You can also use "<Bar>" instead.  See also |map_bar|.
   ```
2. This talks about the usage of many keycodes including `<Bar>` in `:map` command and a few other commands but no mention of the `:command` command. See `:help keycodes`.

   ```
                                            *key-notation* *key-codes* *keycodes*
    These names for keys are used in the documentation.  They can also be used
    with the ":map" command (insert the key name by pressing CTRL-K and then the
    key you want the name for).

    ...

    <Bslash>        backslash               \        92     *backslash* *<Bslash>*
    <Bar>           vertical bar            |       124     *<Bar>*
    <Del>           delete                          127

    ...

    For mapping, abbreviation and menu commands you can then copy-paste the
    examples and use them directly.  Or type them literally, including the '<' and
    '>' characters.  This does NOT work for other commands, like ":set" and
    ":autocmd"!
   ```
3. This one also talks about usage of `<Bar>` in the `:map` command. See `:help map-bar`.

   ```
                                                        *map_bar* *map-bar*
    Since the '|' character is used to separate a map command from the next
    command, you will have to do something special to include  a '|' in {rhs}.
    There are three methods:
       use       works when                    example      ~
       <Bar>     '<' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls <Bar> more^M
       \|        'b' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls \| more^M
       ^V|       always, in Vim and Vi         :map _l :!ls ^V| more^M

    (here ^V stands for CTRL-V; to get one CTRL-V you have to type it twice; you
    cannot use the <> notation "<C-V>" here).
   ```
4. Again, this talks about the `:map` command only. See `:help usr_40`.

   ```
    SPECIAL CHARACTERS

    The ":map" command can be followed by another command.  A | character
    separates the two commands.  This also means that a | character can't be used
    inside a map command.  To include one, use <Bar> (five characters).  Example:
    >
            :map <F8> :write <Bar> !checkin %:S<CR>
   ```

How can we explain the treatment of `<Bar>` as `|` in the `:command` command then?

Comment: Kudos for making a good effort to find the answer yourself in the docs.

Comment: I suspect the answer to this is going to turn out to be that it’s *not* documented, due to oversight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I went digging for this one and as far as I can tell this behavior has been present ever since the user-defined command feature was introduced in Vim 5.2.

Initially I thought this was present because a user comand takes its arguments from `<...>` special sequences, such as `<args>` or `<bang>`, which makes it so that it takes `<lt>` to escape a literal `<`. So I thought the code would use the normal expansion of `<...>` special sequences to handle `<lt>`. But looking at the code, that's not really the case, since special sequences are handled quite early, but `<lt>` is only handled when the command is actually expanded, which is when the other sequences such as `<args>` and `<bang>` are actually replaced.

There is *one* behavior of user-defined commands that *does* depend on this feature, and it's the usage of `<SID>` to be able to run script-local functions from the same script in which the command is defined.

If you'd like to follow along in the code:

- When a user-defined command is defined, [`replace_termcodes()` is called](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/usercmd.c#L871) very early in that definition.
- The code in `replace_termcodes()` is the one that [recognizes the `<SID>` sequence](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/term.c#L5456) and replaces it with an appropriate `<SNR>` sequence including the unique id of the script being sourced.
- That same code block is handling all special `<...>` sequences, including `<Bar>`, but also `<C-X>` or `<Esc>`, etc.
- That code path can't really be disabled by passing additional arguments. Whenever [`&cpo` doesn't include `<`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/term.c#L5408) (which means that `<...>` sequences are enabled), the code in `replace_termcodes()` will replace all special sequences, including `<SID>` but also all the others.

That `<SID>` is allowed in a user-defined command is actually documented, right at the end of [`:help :command`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html) (scroll down to the very end) you'll see (emphasis mine):

> When defining a user command in a script, it will be able to call functions
> local to the script and use mappings local to the script.  When the user
> invokes the user command, it will run in the context of the script it was
> defined in. **This matters if `<SID>` is used in a command.**

So, while `:command` doesn't really *need* to handle sequences such as `<Bar>`, since using `|` is perfectly acceptable in a command body (unlike in `:map`), I guess it was found that it was easier to just let those sequences be expanded in a `:command` replacement text. Unfortunately, this didn't seem to be documented in Vim's help docs, but it seems that this behavior was intentionally introduced (probably as part of supporting use of `<SID>`) and that it was present since user-commands were first introduced in Vim 5.2.

Comment: There's obviously some speculation in my answer, but I think it's probably close enough to the original intent... I took a look at Vim 5.3 source code (couldn't really find 5.2 anywhere, even in official repos) and I found two problems with my argument: First, it seems to use `\<` in a `:command` replacement to escape a `<` instead of `<lt>`, even though `:map` uses `<lt>`. Second, it doesn't really support `<SID>` at all, that was introduced later. So I'm a bit puzzled as to *why* it would originally call `replace_termcodes()`, since the `<SID>` explanation doesn't work there...

Comment: Either way, this is excellent detective work. +1