# autocmd BufNewFile to use template and then run command (to move cursor)

Tags: autocmd

I have a template being used like so:

```
autocmd BufNewFile ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd :silent 0r !vimwiki-diary-template.py
```

But earlier in my autocommands the cursor position is being set which annoyingly moves the cursor to the end of file in this vimwiki diary template.  So I want to set it to a particular position.

Can I do something like `:6<Enter>` at the end of my `BufNewFile` command to then move the cursor to line#6?

Something like:

```
autocmd BufNewFile ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd :silent 0r !vimwiki-diary-template.py && exe :6<Enter>
```

or maybe

```
autocmd BufNewFile ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd :silent 0r !vimwiki-diary-template.py
   \ normal 6gg|zt
```

or something else?

Is it possible to combine these two actions together?

---

solution: adding  `| normal 6G` instead of bash-like  `&&...` at the end of the autocmd works.  And it can even be simply done with  `| 6`.

Comment: I find it odd that your template rule only applies to new files, so I'm wondering how the `BufReadPost` applies there... (Update: It's probably through the `:filetype detect`.) But, still, how will Vim have a location for the `'"` mark if the file is new? Perhaps setting the mark (with `normal! m"` or similar) from the `BufNewFile` would be a good approach.

Comment: Um... I'll add more code to explain...

Comment: Maybe `BufReadPost` does **not** apply here?  I don't know why vim always puts the cursor at the end of the file here, I assumed it was because of how the template created the new file somehow emulated a cursor-position, but that's just my ignorant guess.

Comment: re: ""Perhaps setting the mark (with normal! m" or similar) from the BufNewFile would be a good approach"" can that be added in `augroup templates`... to the `autocmd BufNewFile`?  How does that get done?  I don't know who commands can be combined like that.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the autocmd that restores the cursor... But simply after executing a `:read` command, Vim will leave the cursor at the end of the input that was read. Nevertheless, just setting the cursor after reading the input should be enough. Ben's solution below should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim’s command separator is `|`, but it cannot come after certain commands. In this case the simplest workaround is `execute`:

```
autocmd Event pattern execute '0read !cmd' | 6
```

Another solution is to use multiple autocommands, as they are executed in sequence:

```
autocmd Event pattern 0read !cmd
autocmd Event pattern 6
```

Comment: adding ` \| 6` to the end of my autcmd is resulting in the template generating its content twice, redundant content and the cursor position isn't set.

Comment: Did you use execute? With the !, the bar is consumed as part of a shell program.

Comment: Oh, I see you say `!cmd` but earlier you wrote just `\| 6` and I wasn't, and still am not, sure how to assemble them into a workable solution.

Comment: @alec I included execute in the code snippet; perhaps I am missing something, but cmd is your python script (I’m on mobile, and copy/paste is a bit hard, so I got lazy)

Comment: um I could edit your post and past in my broken command then you could fix it?  if that would be easier and you wouldn't mind?  sorry.  I keep trying variations based on these hints but keep getting errors or the redundant content.

Comment: Why not put the error and the code in a comment?

Comment: `autocmd BufNewFile ~/Documents/wiki/diary/[0-9]\\\{4\}-[0-9]\\\{2\}-[0-9]\\\{2\}.mkd :silent 0r !vimwiki-diary-template.py \| normal 6gg` results in redundant content so does `autocmd BufNewFile ~/Documents/wiki/diary/[0-9]\\\{4\}-[0-9]\\\{2\}-[0-9]\\\{2\}.mkd :silent 0r !vimwiki-diary-template.py \| 6`

Comment: You’re missing `:execute`

Comment: @alec You need `:execute` so the `\|` isn't passed to the shell: `autocmd BufNewFile ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd execute 'silent 0r !vimwiki-diary-template.py' \| 6`

Comment: @alec See [`:help :bar`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar) and note that `:read !` is one of the commands affected. That section suggests using `:execute` as a workaround. (See `:help :execute` as well...)

Comment: `autocmd BufNewFile ~/Documents/wiki/diary/*.mkd execute 'silent 0r !vimwiki-diary-template.py' \| 6` is giving me `Invalid expression: \| 6`.  and if I change that to `\| normal 6G` it's still invalid expression.

Comment: @filbranden what do you think? No escape, double escape?

Comment: No escape necessary!  `|` needs to be escaped when being used in an argument.  But apparently works on its own equivalent to bash `&&` in autocmd to give multiple commands in one line.

Comment: @alec Vimscript is unfortunately much more tricky than bash! Meaning of `|` actually depends on the context you're in. See, for example, https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/26806/18609 In any case, it looks like here you need no backslash and `|` by itself works fine, which is great!

Comment: oh dear, the cursor position is being successfully set but the redundant conent is still appearing, the template being produced twice :(

Comment: @filbranden any ideas?  `| 6`, `| normal 6G`, `| normal! 6G`, `| normal 6gg`, `| normal! 6gg`, all producing content twice.   I thought it was working perfectly a moment ago :(

Comment: Could it be the program @alec ? Might debug its arguments with/without. Are things still working without the cursor setting? Does the second version work?

Comment: oh it was because I had the autocmd redundantly in my vimrc, so the script was being invoked twice, geez.  Thank you both so much <3

Comment: If you also want to keep the `zt`, then `| normal! 6Gzt` (after the `execute`) is the way to go. To avoid duplicated autocmd's if you reload your vimrc, use an `augroup` and clean it with `au!` before defining your commands, see `:help :augroup` for details.